# c3js How does one format a timestamp from seconds since the epoch to a normal date?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Here is my fiddle with relevant code: http://jsfiddle.net/hfznh45w/13/

So, I'm using C3.js, and am trying to make a timeseries graph and am having issues with the date formats.

This is what I'm using to convert seconds since epoch to a date string:

```
function dateToString(e) {
    var date = new Date(e * 1000);
    return date.toDateString().substring(4);
}
```

and here is how I'm calling the above function:

```
 x1: {
  type: 'timeseries',
  show: true,
  tick: {
    fit: true,
    format: function(e, d){
      return dateToString(e)
    }
  }
},
```

But it seems like those functions never get called (console.logs are never invoked when I put them in the functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would suggest is that convert the data into the correct date format at the data level

```
regTimes = [];
incTimes = [];
registrationTimes.forEach(function(e){regTimes.push(new Date(e * 1000))});

incomeTimes.forEach(function(e){incTimes.push(new Date(e * 1000))});
```

Now feed the regTimes and incTimes as data something like this:

```
 columns: [
         ['x1'].concat(regTimes),
         ['x2'].concat(incTimes),
         ['Registrations'].concat(registrations),
         ['Income'].concat(incomes)
       ],
```

Also provide the date tick format of your choice like this:

```
tick: {
                format: function (x) { return x.getSeconds(); }

            }
```

full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/hfznh45w/16/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the jsfiddle. that helps a ton! While I don't want seconds as my label, getting the datetime to parse correctly was the main issue. I'll post my jsfiddle as I want once I get the format / label spacing happy.